# Filtering rooms by users

Tags: python, django

I have a ChatRoom model that has a users field. And I need to get a model in Views in which the users = request field.user and user.

I get the error 'local variable 'myroom'referenced before assignment'.
Help to get the object using the get method.

models.py

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

Views.py

```
def homechat(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.POST
        user = list(user)[1]
        user = USER.objects.get(username=user)

        try:
            room = ChatRoom.objects.get(Q(users=user) & Q(users=request.user))
            return redirect('room', room=room.pk)
        except room.DoesNotExist:
            room = ChatRoom.objects.create(users1=user, users2=request.user)
            room.save()
            return redirect('room', room=room.pk)
    return render(request, 'chatapp/index.html')
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML form, `list(user)[1]` looks a very bad idea.